# How can I rename network interfaces in CoreOS 1010.6.0?

Tags: coreos

All of my servers use ens802f0 as the primary Ethernet interface except one which has insisted on using ens802f1.

How can I change the names of the interfaces? I would like to rename ens802f1 to ens802f0 but can find no file where the interfaces are defined or configured.
cbr0 contains the MAC address of NIC without a link, ens802f0.

networkctl says,

```
IDX LINK             TYPE               OPERATIONAL SETUP     
  1 lo               loopback           carrier     configured
  2 eno1             ether              routable    configured
  3 ens802f0         ether              no-carrier  configured
  4 eno2             ether              no-carrier  configured
  5 ens802f1         ether              degraded    configured
  6 cbr0             ether              no-carrier  configured
```

Comment: I don't remember the details because I haven't done it in a long time, but look into udev rules.

Answer (score 0):

Physically plug the cable into the other port of that NIC.

Multiple port cards are usually what same **s**lot index but different **f**unction index means.

Comment: I tried that. I can't understand why this didn't work.

Comment: What interface comes up with the other port?

Answer (score 0):

You might check the configuration file under /etc/systemd/network/
and rename it, however you have to change the  ens802f0 and set another name, 
but if you change the cable order it's the best way at least you wants  to change also the second interface name.

Comment: I had no ens802f0.network in /etc/systemd/network/. Fixed that so that ens802f0 has the correct IP, but the link is still on the wrong NIC.

Comment: I tried swapping cables. The link stays with ens802f1.